# How do calculate <p|x>?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, fourier-transform

In my quantum mechanics lectures it says that the relation between the basis $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ is given by:

$\langle p | x \rangle = \Large \frac{e^{-ip x/ \hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \, .$

However, i'm not sure how to go about proving this relation. My idea was that the eigenstates of momentum can be written as below:

$\phi(x,p) = \Large \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} e^{ipx/\hbar},$

which form an orthogonal basis.

But, we can expand any state, $|\text{state}\rangle$, in terms of the othorgonal basis right?

$|x\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) |p'\rangle dp'$

If it were correct then the following would also be correct?

Using the fact that $\langle p | p' \rangle = \delta(p - p')$, $\langle p | x \rangle$ can be computed:

\begin{align}
\langle p | x \rangle
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) \langle p | p' \rangle dp' \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) \delta(p - p') dp' \\
=& \phi(p, x) \\
=& \Large \frac{e^{ip x/ \hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}
\end{align}
as required.

I.e. **Clearly the exponent here does not have a minus sign where as in the lecture notes, it does. Where am I making a mistake?**

EDIT:

Someone flagged as a duplicate so I couldn't provide answer.

The statement that:
$|x\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) |p'\rangle dp'$
is wrong.

In order to expand in another basis, you should have essentially up with an integral of the basis states multiplied by some factor that tells you how much that state contributes to the end result i.e. an overlap. You can prove that the expansion of states is actually written:

$|p\rangle = \int \langle x | p \rangle | x \rangle dx$ which leads to the required results.

Comment: $\phi(p,x)$ is, by **definiton**, equal to $\langle x|p\rangle$. If you want $\langle p|x\rangle$ instead, you just need to calculate the complex conjugate of this.

Comment: Thanks :) But It doesn't explain what it wrong with my working out above. Do you know where I've made a mistake? Or is the mistake in the lecture notes?

Comment: So, if I'm to expand any set of states in terms of another orthogonal set of states, I always use the complex conjugate? (as it's essentially an overlap integral?)

Comment: But I thought the eigenstates of momentum had no minus sign? for example see: http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node138.html

Comment: I have to say I'm really confused by your notation: what does $\phi$ stand for? what is your definition of $\phi$?

Comment: $\phi$ are eigenstates of momentum in my definition. And it says in the document that the eigestates of momentum, u, are http://postimg.org/image/kosthfqwp/. So surely $u=p$?

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion! Thank you for helping! :) I just feeling like there's either something wrong in my initial statements or that the lecture notes are wrong in some way

Comment: Ahhh haaa - I think I know where my mistake is. Will write up an answer

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178168/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41880/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Please don't use the *question* box for an *answer*.

Comment: Someone closed the question so I couldn't provide an answer.