# Value of $ \langle x | p \rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In a context of quantum mechanics, why does:

$$ \langle x | p \rangle = \left(\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\right)^{3/2} e^{ipx/\hbar} $$

Is there any proof for this?

Comment: Hi Tom. I've typseset what I think you're asking. If I've got this wrong it should be obvious how to modify the Latex to correct it or you could just roll back the edit.

Comment: I was totally forget about how to edit latex in stackoverflow. Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted to write!

Comment: @DanielSank Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted. I will close this question.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41880/2451