# How can I derive $\langle p | x \rangle=e^\frac{px}{i\hbar}$ without resorting to wave mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, hilbert-space, fourier-transform

$$\langle p | x \rangle=e^\frac{px}{i\hbar}$$ can pretty easily be derived from wave mechanics. But how can it be derived without resorting to it? I've seen it be derived from the translation operator $\hat T$. It is shown that for an infinitesimal displacement $\epsilon$ the translation operator in the position eigenbasis is:
$$\langle x |\hat T |\psi\rangle=\left( 1+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\langle x | \psi\rangle=\left( 1+\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi_x$$
In which $\psi_x$ is the state vector's representation in position space, such that
$$|\psi\rangle=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\psi_x |x\rangle dx$$
And it then assumes that because momentum generates translation, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{i}{\hbar}\hat p$.

Now this leaves me rather unsatisfied. Is there any way to prove the form of the momentum operator, and from it prove $$\langle p | x \rangle=e^\frac{px}{i\hbar}$$ using, for example, the matrix representation of quantum mechanics?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41880/2451

Comment: $e^{ikx}$ describes a plane wave. Why would anyone want to derive this without a wave equation?