# Eigenfunction/eigenvalue of the momentum operator and inner product of $x$ and $p$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, wavefunction, hilbert-space, fourier-transform

I am reading a paper on the Wigner function and during a calculation they used $$\langle x|p\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}e^{\frac{ixp}{\hbar}}$$ and referenced Griffiths "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" p. 103.

I looked it up and there they want to find the eigenfunctions and eigenvalues of the momentum operator.

$$
-i\hbar \frac{d}{dx} f_p(x) = p f_p(x) \\
\Rightarrow f_p(x) = A e^{\frac{ixp}{\hbar}}.
$$

By restricting the eigenvalues to real numbers and setting $A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}$ they get orthonormality

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^*_{p^{'}}(x) f_p(x) dx = |A|^2 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{i(p-p')x}{\hbar}} dx = |A|^2 2\pi \hbar \delta(p-p') = \delta(p-p'). 
$$

Therefore

$$f_p(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}} e^{\frac{ixp}{\hbar}}.$$

How does this connect to the above inner product of $x$ and $p$ and how can I obtain the inner product's solution from this?

Comment: Is this not just the statement that to change basis from position to momentum space one uses a fourier transform?

Comment: For a discrete basis, orthonormality reads $\langle e_i, e_j\rangle= \delta_{ij}$. So for a continuous basis $f_p$ as above one naturaly requires orthonormality in the form $\langle f_p, f_q\rangle=\delta(p-q)$. Notice that $A$ has been chosen to satisfy this.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41880/2451

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially a notational issue. In Dirac notation, a pure state is represented by a vector (ket) in Hilbert space $|\Psi\rangle$ which contains all the information that one can have about that state. The eigenvectors of momentum are then denoted as $|p\rangle$. This notation is representationally independent - i.e. it does not assume you are in the position representation or the momentum representation. The ket $|p\rangle$ represents the *state* and says nothing about in which representation it's in. In order to get $|p\rangle$ in the *position representation* we take the inner product of it with position eigenvector $|x\rangle$. So the position representation of $|p\rangle$ is denoted in Dirac notation by $\langle x |p\rangle$. This position representation of the momentum eigenvector is exactly that Griffiths calculated on page 103.

Answer (score 2):

To speak about this precisely, one has to built up the setting a bit more carefully. It is also a bit of an abuse to use the term Hilbert space since this functions are not formally a basis for the space, given that they are not normalizable. So I would suggest, to gain some insight on your question, to consider instead of $x\in(-\infty,\infty)$, take $x\in[-1,1]$. Along with the condition of $f$ being square-integrable. Eventually this is called $\mathcal{H}=\mathcal{L}^2([-1,1])$ which is a proper Hilbert space. It turns out that the Fourier transform is a unitary automorphism of this space, so that you can think of $x$ and $p$ as two bases (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_L2). One can then realize the dual space $\mathcal{H}^*$ is itself and treat $\mathcal{H}$ in let's say $p$ coordinates and $\mathcal{H}^*$ in $x$ coordinates while the relation being the automorphism. A bit Functional analysis will serve the purpose of explaining all this in detail. (*The formalism is always deeper in comparison to how the concepts are discovered*)

The physical(ist) approach (I will ignore factors of $2\pi$, so forgive me for that :) ) is looking to solve the eigenfunction equation of the momentum operator (obviously real values, since that is what one can measure in the lab) and build a complete base out of it. Once you have solved for the eigenfunctions as above, you should be able to express any state, even $| x\rangle$ in this new base. So what you do is project into every basis element $|p\rangle$. 
$$|x\rangle = \int dp |p\rangle \langle p|x\rangle$$
However you have implicitly imposed the Fourier relation when you were solving the eigenfunction equation, since 
$$-i\hslash \frac{d}{dx}f_p(x) = p f_p(x)$$
is turned into **through a Fourier transform** (including the $\hslash$ in the kernel), which 
$$p'\tilde{f}_p(p') = p \tilde{f}_p(p')$$
which is solved by picking $p=p'$ (so we can drop the subindex $p$ on the Fourier version while adding the subscript to the $x$ position to which it is associated, as written below), which is basically telling you any function of just $p$ can be converted into an eigenfunction if you transform it via a Fourier transform back to $x$. Up to this point you could pick any set of those functions (depending just on $p$) to be your new basis. So that if you wanted to write this functions in terms of $x$ then you employ the inverse Fourier transform to get:
$$f_p(x) = \int dp\; e^{ipx/\hslash}\tilde{f}(p)$$
And where as pointed out before, $\tilde{f}(p)=\langle p|f\rangle$ is the projection of $f$ into the basis labeled by $p$.
Having imposed that the relation between the coordinates is a fourier transform and demanding orthonormality, you can determine suitable $f$'s.