# Is my expansion of the state $| x \rangle$ correct?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, momentum, hilbert-space, fourier-transform

In my quantum mechanics textbook it says that the relation between the basis $|x\rangle$ and $|p\rangle$ is given by:

$\langle p | x \rangle = \Large \frac{e^{-ip x/ \hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \, .$

However, i'm not sure how to go about proving this relation. My idea was that the eigenstates of momentum can be written as below:

$\phi(x,p) = \Large \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} e^{-ipx/\hbar},$

which form an orthogonal basis.

But, we can expand any state, $|\text{state}\rangle$, in terms of the othorgonal basis right? **So is my notation below correct for the expansion of the state $| x \rangle$** ?

$|x\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) |p'\rangle dp'$

If it were correct then the following would also be correct?

Using the fact that $\langle p | p' \rangle = \delta(p - p')$, $\langle p | x \rangle$ can be computed:

\begin{align}
\langle p | x \rangle
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) \langle p | p' \rangle dp' \\
=& \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \phi(p', x) \delta(p - p') dp' \\
=& \phi(p, x) \\
=& \Large \frac{e^{-ip x/ \hbar}}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}
\end{align}
as required.

Does the logic work here?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178168/2451, http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41880/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I've always thought of them as two different notations for the same thing: the amplitude of finding the particle a $x$ given $p$, (or vice versa).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proof for $\langle q| p \rangle = e^{ipq}$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41077/)

Comment: Note that you do have broken logic. You have posited $\phi(x,p)=e^{ixp}/\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}$, and it's perfectly reasonable to expand $$|x⟩=\int \chi(x,p')|p'⟩\mathrm dp',$$ but then there is nothing to guarantee that $\phi=\chi$. For more details, see the linked duplicates.